# Counting users in a geo location

Tags: android, ajax, html

I would like to implement a user count in a particular location on a map in HTML5. The HTML5 code would be implemented inside an Android application. Here are the steps what i have thought of:

1. Store the latitudes & longitudes of the location in a server side database.
2. Store a counter variable at server side database.
3. Users opens the Android application (current location calculated).
4. If current location is approx = to stored location then

=> XMLHttpRequest object sent to database server that stores the user's IP address and increments the counter

I have two issues. One is how to identify a user so that it is counted only once. IP address is not a very good way of doing that as it can be different for same user (user using Wifi and 3G). Second is to keep on updating the user list every 3-5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

First I would recommend to use geofences (see http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) for the location you want to track. That way you don't really need to handle the location yourself, but your app gets notified when a user enters (or leaves) the given area (location + radius).

To identify the user I'd suggest to create a UUID ( [http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29) ), store it locally (e.g. in a SharedPreference ) and send it along with the location update...

I'm not sure about keeping the list up to date, since I'm not really familiar with ajax...